How can the Moment Coefficient with elevator deflection be obtained?
For the range of linear lift, the canard moment coefficient about the aerodynamic center is:
$C_{m_c}=C_{m_c0} +C_{m_c,\delta_e}\delta_e $
Where

$C_{m_c0}$ is the pitching moment coefficient without any control surface deflection, and its value can be found by using the airfoil data.
$C_{m_c,\delta_e}$ is the change in moment coefficient with respect to elevator deflection.
$\delta_e$ is the elevator deflection angle.

Is there a way to find the value of the second term $C_{m_c,\delta_e}$?

As usual in those cases the USAF STABILITY AND CONTROL DATCOM is the way to go.
In particular, section 6.1.2. at page 1945 of the .pdf contains the methods that you need. At page 1949 a very simple method is presented suitable for plain flap/elevator:

Pitching-moment increments for plain trailing-edge flaps are presented in Figure 6.1.2.1-35b. These increments are given about the quarter-chord, based on the square of the airfoil chord c², as a function of flap deflection and the ratio of flap chord to airfoil chord cf/c. This figure is limited to the linear-lift range and subcritical Mach numbers.



Thank you, Sophit  much better now.

@DeltaLima: you're welcome
